# Check users ip on application load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

How to get ip of user on application start or load? 
and validate the requested ip from database

Comment: When the application starts, there is no user.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`Request.UserHostAddress` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx).

Comment: but i need to check on global.asax page's application start  application start

Comment: @Noname: 
When the application starts, there is no user.

Comment: i need to check the visitor's ip from my database who requesting to page is not in blacklisted in database if not so visitor can access application else redirect to another page. so how is it possible ?

Comment: this was the solution blackList(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]) :) thanks u